# Curvature of curve at the given parametric value

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

The given is:
$$r(t)=t \pmb i +\frac{1}{36}t^3 \pmb j \space,t=3$$
Using the following formula where $K$ is the curvature:
$$K=\frac{||T^{'}(t)||}{||v(t)||}$$
$$T(t)= \frac{v(t)}{||v(t)||} =\frac{\sqrt {145}}{12}\pmb i+\frac{\sqrt {145}}{144}t^2\pmb j$$
$$T^{'}(t)=\frac{\sqrt{145}}{72}t\pmb j$$
So now we have $K$ to be:
$$K=\frac{\sqrt{145}}{72}*\frac{12}{\sqrt{145}}$$
$$K=\frac{1}{6}$$
But this isn't correct, I've went through this three times and only now got $\frac{1}{6}$.
I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r(t)=t \pmb i +\frac{1}{36}t^3 \pmb j$

$v(t) = r'(t) = (1, \frac{t^2}{12})$

$||v(t)|| = \frac{\sqrt {t^4 + 144}} {12}$ ...(1)

So, unit tangent vector of $r(t),$ $\, T(t) = (\frac {12} {\sqrt {t^4 + 144}}, \frac {t^2} {\sqrt {t^4 + 144}})$

Normal vector $\, T'(t) = \displaystyle (- \frac {24t^3} {(t^4 + 144)^{3/2}}, \frac {2t} {\sqrt {t^4 + 144}} - \frac {2t^5} {(t^4 + 144)^{3/2}})$ ...(ii)

At $\, t = 3$,

From (i), $||v(t)|| = \frac{5} {4}$

From (ii), $T'(t) = \displaystyle (- \frac {24} {125}, \frac {32} {125})$

$||T'(t)|| = \displaystyle \frac {8} {25}$

Comment: So $K=\frac{8}{25}*\frac{4}{5}$?

Comment: Yes that should give $K$.